# What join/model arrangement would be appropriate here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been reading up on the various types of relationships possible under ActiveRecord, and I'm in that position where I think I understand all the details in an abstract but they haven't really *clicked* for me. I would really appreciate a little advice on this issue.

In my practice application, I am dealing with four concrete things: viewers, TV shows, discs of those shows, and episodes. Then there's one abstract thing, the viewer<->show or 'subscription'/'who watches what' relationship, which is where I run into trouble.

## Summary

- Each `Owner` watches several `Show`s.
- Each `Show` has many `Episode`s.
- An `Episode` belongs to one `Show`.
- An `Owner` owns many `Disc`s.
- A `Disc` belongs to a show, but has many `Episode`s on it.
- The same `Disc` can be owned by many `Owner`s, but there needs to be a way to see if an `Owner` owns a specific `Disc` -- the fact they simply watch the `Show` the `Disc` belongs to isn't enough, there has to be a boolean 'Owned?' somewhere.

I need to pull data out to neatly answer questions like:

- What shows does User *X* watch?
- Who watches Show *Y*?
- How many discs does User *X* own?
- What episodes are on Disc *Z*?
- What episodes are not on any discs yet?
- Does User *X* not own any discs of shows they watch?

## My Best Guess

- `Subscription` `belongs_to :owner` and `belongs_to :show`
- Join table, `subscriptions`, with two columns: `t.references :owner`, `t.references :show`
- `Owner` `has_many :discs` and `has_many :shows, through: :subscriptions`
- `Show` `has_many :discs` and `has_many :owners, through: :subscriptions`
- `Show` `has_many :episodes`
- `Episode` `belongs_to :show` and `belongs_to :disc`
- `Disc` `has_many :episodes` and `belongs_to_many :owners`

## Problem

It's just fuzzy and jumbled around in my head, and I'm not sure about using the join table like that or if it's proper to use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. I've mocked it up a couple of times today, but the combination of trying to nail the queries and unfamiliar syntax and trying to grasp or properly create the relationships is leading to some frustration and confusion. I'd really appreciate someone pointing out some mistake I've made, letting me know the 'Railsy' way to do this, or explaining what the proper relationship structure should be.

Comment: belongs_to_many doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I'd do:

Owner:

```
has_many: subscriptions
has_many: disks, through: :subscriptions
```

Show:

```
has_many :episodes
has_many :disks
```

Episode:

```
belongs_to :show
belongs_to :disk
```

Disk:

```
belongs_to :show
has_many :subscriptions
has_many :owners, through: :subscriptions
has_many :episodes
```

Subscription:

```
belongs_to: owner
belongs_to: disk
```

That should work. The only thing that isn't there is Owner-Show relationship. And I think that is the best, since there really isn't a real-life connection. The only real connection is through the disks (if you don't own any disks of a show, then you don't watch that show). What you can do to get all the shows the `owner` watches (and visa-versa) is by:

```
@shows = @owner.disks.map(&:show).flatten.uniq
@owners = @show.disks.map(&:owners).flatten.uniq
```

Those last two lines are untested, but I believe they should work fine.